# method_missing override is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I wrote a convenience ActiveRecord extension to delegate methods to a base object (based on [multi-table inheritance](http://mediumexposure.com/multiple-table-inheritance-active-record/))

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.acts_as(base)
    class_eval %Q{
      def method_missing(method, *args, &blk)
        #{base}.send(method, *args, &blk)
      rescue NoMethodError
        super
      end
    }
  end
end
```

I have a *state* class and a *base* class

```
# state class
class MyState < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :my_object
  acts_as :my_object
end

# base class
class MyObject < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :head, :class_name => 'MyState'
  has_one :tail, :class_name => 'MyState'
end
```

When I tried this out, I found out that it doesn't work in some cases.  More specifically,

```
> MyState.first.some_method_in_base
nil
> MyObject.first.tail.some_method_in_base
NoMethodError: undefined method `some_method_in_base' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::HasOneAssociation:0xABCDEFG>
```

Can anyone enlighten me as to why one works and the other doesn't?

Comment: I'd also suggest using the ActiveSupport provided version of this, which is called #delegate: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#M000051

Comment: Yep, I ended up using delegates, but they aren't as convenient as the concept of forwarding all missing methods to a base class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you run `MyObject.first.tail` the object that actually responds is an [AssociationProxy](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb) class that

> has most of the basic instance methods removed, and delegates
>       # unknown methods to @target via
>   method_missing

You can get more details about the proxy running:

```
MyObject.first.proxy_owner
MyObject.first.proxy_reflection
MyObject.first.proxy_target
```

If you look in the code, you can see that the AssociationProxy proxies the method some_method_in_base to your MyState class **only if *MyState* responds to *some_method_in_base*** as you can see in the code below.

```
  private
    # Forwards any missing method call to the \target.
    def method_missing(method, *args, &block)
      if load_target
        if @target.respond_to?(method)
          @target.send(method, *args, &block)
        else
          super
        end
      end
    end
```

Therefore, the **method_missing** you have defined in the **target class** is never called.

Comment: I saw the method_missing definition in AssociationProxy before, but I just couldn't figure out what it did.  This makes perfect sense.  Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! And welcome to the StackOverflow community! If the answer was correct and helped you, you should mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer. You can also vote it up, if you want. More info on http://stackoverflow.com/faq on section 'How do I ask questions here?'

Comment: There you go.  The checkbox is obscure.  Thanks for pointing it out.