# method_missing and association_proxy in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, method-missing

So, here's my problem. I currently am building a simple authentication system for a rails site. I have 3 classes for this: Person, Session, and Role. In my Person model I have defined `method_missing` to dynamically capture roles according to [this guide](http://metautonomo.us/2008/09/30/easy-role-based-authorization/).

In my application_controller I have some logic to deal with logins and log-outs, the result of which gives me the currently logged in user via:
    `@user = @application_session.person`
Where `@application_session` is the current session

Now in one of my controllers, I don't want anyone to be able to do anything unless they are an admin, so I included:
    `before_filter @user.is_an_admin?`

This raises a `NoMethodError`, even though I have `method_missing` defined in my model. I tried defining `is_an_admin?`, having it always return true as a test, and that works.

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3386567/method-missing-override-is-not-working), I think the problem might have something to do with proxy associations. When I run:
    `puts @user.proxy_owner`
I get a session object, since each user (Person) can have many sessions, and I got my user (Person) from the current session.

I am very confused why `@user.is_an_admin?` is not calling the method_missing method in my Person controller. Please let me know if you need more information or code snippets.

I am using Rails 3 on Ruby 1.9

Comment: how is @user set? is there a filter before the before filter?

Comment: yes, `@user` is set in a before_filter in the application_controller, than `@user.is_an_admin?` is called in the reports_controller. I also tried `@user.is_an_admin?` in the index method of that controller for debugging purposes and received the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider a method_missing an overkill for such task.

Now, if you have Session class, which belongs_to User, then you can have this:

```
class Session
  belongs_to :user, :extend => PermissionMixin
end

class User
  include PermissionMixin
end

module PermissionMixin
  def admin?
    if cond
      true
    else
     false
    end
  end
end
```

P.S. Check [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan), perhaps it'll suit your needs better.

Comment: That would probably suit my immediate needs, but I want to build this to be expandable. I want to be able to add more user roles later, without having to write an "is_a_role?" method for each one. I'll take a look at cancan, thanks.

Comment: You can have method_missing in this mixin, I just don't like the concept.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by moving the `method_missing` method to my `application_controller.rb`. I change the logic of the method a little to check for a user, and if found, dynamically check the role. If things were not kosher, I had the method redirect to `root_url` or return true if the user matched the requested roles.

Finally, in my reports controller, I used `before_filter :is_an_admin?` and got my desired results. However, I am still unclear as to why `method_missing` had to be defined in my application controller as opposed to directly in the Person (aka `@user`) model?

Answer (score 0):

I use a similar permissions check in my system to check the User > Role > Permissions association:
`User.current_user.can_sysadmin?`

In my controllers I have to instead use: 
`User.current_user.send('can_sysadmin?')`

This may work for you as well.