# Rails: method_missing is not called on model when using associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, belongs-to, method-missing

My current code:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  def method_missing name
    true
  end
end

Category.new.ex_undefined_method          #=> true
Product.last.category.ex_undefined_method #=> NoMethodError: undefined method `ex_undefined_method' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::BelongsToAssociation:0xc4cd52c>
```

This happens because of this code in rails which only passes methods that exist to the model.

```
private
def method_missing(method, *args)
  if load_target
    if @target.respond_to?(method)
      if block_given?
        @target.send(method, *args)  { |*block_args| yield(*block_args) }
      else
        @target.send(method, *args)
      end
    else
      super
    end
  end
end
```

This is what I want:

```
Product.last.category.ex_undefined_method #=> true
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You have a typo in your `Product` `belongs_to` line. Is that in the original code, or just the code posted here?

Comment: This is very similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3386567/method-missing-override-is-not-working. I could probably override method_missing on the BelongsToAssociation class, but that seems a little too universal.. No?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that the `AssociationProxy` object only sends on methods that the target claims to `respond_to?`. Therefore, the fix here is to update `respond_to?` as well:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  def method_missing(name, *args, &block)
    if name =~ /^handleable/
      "Handled"
    else
      super
    end
  end

  def respond_to?(name)
    if name =~ /^handleable/
      true
    else
      super
    end
  end
end
```

In fact, you should *always* update `respond_to?` if you redefine `method_missing` - you've changed the interface of your class, so you need to make sure that everyone knows about it. See [here](http://www.dcmanges.com/blog/30).

Answer (score 2):

[Chowlett's response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198058/rails-method-missing-is-not-called-on-model-when-using-associations/6198586#6198586) is indeed the way to go imho.

But, if you are using Rails 3*, make sure to include [the second argument](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html) that has been introduced in the responds_to? definition:

```
def respond_to?(name,include_private = false)
  if name =~ /^handleable/
    true
  else
    super 
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
if @target.respond_to?(method)
  if block_given?
    @target.send(method, *args)  { |*block_args| yield(*block_args) }
  else
    @target.send(method, *args)
  end
else
  super
end
```

by

```
if block_given?
  @target.send(method, *args)  { |*block_args| yield(*block_args) }
else
  @target.send(method, *args)
end
```

As monkey patch to the AssociationProxy

Comment: I always feel nasty when monkey patching. I taught there would be a better way!